# is or will be required to do something

Tags: verbs

1. You **are** required to take care of my cat after I go out of town tomorrow.
2. You'**ll be** required to take care of my cat after I go out of town tomorrow.
3. He was advised that he **was** required to sometimes work long hours.
4. He was advised that he **would be** required to sometimes work long hours.

Q1) Are they all correct? If so, what is the difference between 1) and 2) or 3) and 4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You are required to take care of my cat after I go out of town tomorrow."

This means you are presently required to do so.

"You'll be required to take care of my cat after I go out of town tomorrow."

This means you will be required to do so (in the future).

"He was advised that he was required to sometimes work long hours."

This means that at the time he was advised (in the past), he was required to sometimes work long hours.

"He was advised that he would be required to sometimes work long hours."

This means that he was told in the past that he would have to work long hours in the future.

All four are correct, and each version could act like its counterpart, but #2 and #4 are the most natural.